# Web scraping with a pop-up (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net, web-scraping, popup

I'm trying to scrape a page, but when I login the page displays a pop up before the page that I need (Welcome to blah-blah-blah...don't hit refresh as it will slow the process...etc.etc...).

Naturally, HttpWebRequest scrapes THIS data and not the page that follows.

The popup self cancels so if I could just get the HttpWebRequest to wait a second or two and then scrape, it would work - or - if I can get it to do two scrapes (and I simply discard the 1st one) in the same session then that would work too.

Here's the code:

```
Dim CookieJar As New CookieContainer
Dim Request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(TextBox1.Text)
Request.CookieContainer = New CookieContainer()
Request.CookieContainer.Add(New Uri(TextBox1.Text),
          New Cookie("id", "1234"))
Request.PreAuthenticate = True
Request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
Request.UserAgent = "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)"
Request.AllowAutoRedirect = True
Request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 4
Request.MaximumResponseHeadersLength = 4

Dim Response As WebResponse = DirectCast(Request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

Dim WebResult As String = New StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()
TextBox2.Text = WebResult
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Are you not able to simply login then use the same webrequest to direct yourself to that url?

Comment: Try `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)` this will pause by 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds)

Comment: @ProNinjaCat The problem seems to be that with WebRequest it creates a new instance (WebRequest.CreateHttp) so it seems that the whole thing starts all over again. If there was a "WebRequest.UseTheSameTCPsocket" (or something like this) I think it would work.

Comment: @3vts  yeah, I thought about this too, but it did't work. I placed it after the "Dim Response" (didn't work) and after the "Dim Request" (didn't work either) but it still came up with the same thing. It seems that once you launch the "webrequest" it takes off immediately. I'm pretty sure that HttpWebRequest is it's own subroutine and for the timeout to work you'd have to break in to that routine (just a guess on my part).

Comment: @ProNinjaCat - maybe I misunderstood...is there a way to "re-use" or "redirect" the request?

Comment: Can you please share the URL? There might be some workarounds but I need to check what kink of popup you get

Comment: I wish I could...its an internal website behind our firewall.

Comment: Here is the HTML that the app returns:   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>HP Service Manager Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/9.41.4014/topaz.css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/sm/css/typography.css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/sm/images/1434990761310/HPLogoSolidBlue.ico" />

Comment: here is part 2: <style id="antiClickjacking">body{display:none !important;}</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
...i chopped out some java code to fit this in...
</script>
</head>
<body onkeydown="javascript:onKeyDown();" class="loadingPageBody" onload="refresh();">
<div class="loadingPageMessage">
 <ul>
    <li class="loadingPageHeader">
      <div class="loadingPageLogo"></div>
      <span>PRODUCTION</span>
    </li>

Comment: and part 3:       <li class="loadingPageInfo"><span>Login is in progress, please wait ...</span><br /><br /><img src="cwc/images/progress_bar_large.gif" /> </li>
    <li class="loadingPageNotes">Please DO NOT refresh this page to avoid slowing down the login process.</li>
    <li class="loadingPageCopyright">&copy; 1994-2016 Hewlett-Packard Development Company, L.P.  All rights reserved.<br/> This software is protected by international copyright law.</li>
 </ul>